# Main action bar does not show on 2.3.6 device, but the contextual bar works correctly

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I just deployed an `ActionBarSherlock` app to a `2.3.6` device, but the main action bar does not show.  I tested the contextual action bar on a ListView item, and it works correctly.  I am using `Theme.Sherlock.Light` for my theme.  Any idea what could be causing this problem?

### Additional Information:

- [Samsung Galaxy Ace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Ace)
- LDPI - 480 x 320
- Targeting API Level 18
- Min API Level 10

### Edit 1:

I wanted to add this in case it may be related, maps v2 also doesn't load correctly on the `Galaxy Ace`.

Comment: I've had some issues building actionbars for gingerbread with gradle. So that can be a factor. Where ant wouldn't have this problem

Comment: @CQM I am using Eclipse, no Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake on my part.  I was extending `OrmLiteBaseActivity` and not `SherlockActivity`.  In case someone using `OrmLite` happens upon this question, you can get the `helper` by calling `(DatabaseHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class)` instead of using `getHelper`.